# Mail gem - how to clean up the body string

Tags: ruby, email, ticket-system, ticket-tracking

I'm trying to read an email using ruby mail gem. 
But `mail.body.decoded` returns me not just the body message. How can I clean up this body message and remove unwanted text like:

`-20cf30433c9a437cc304939017ef\nContent-Type: text/plain; charset=ISO-8859-1\nContent-`

```
message = $stdin.read
mail = Mail.read_from_string(message)
puts mail.body.decoded
```

`--20cf30433c9a437cc304939017ef\nContent-Type: text/plain; charset=ISO-8859-1\nContent-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable\n\n REAL BODY TEXT \\n\n--20cf30433c9a437cc304939017ef\nContent-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\nContent-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable\n\n<br clear=3D\"all\">--20cf30433c9a437cc304939017ef--`

How can I clean up this email body mail message extracting only the REAL BODY TEXT , without ANY header ?

I'm creating a simple Ticket System based in Ruby on Rails, and a ticket is created when an email is received by ticket@mydomain.com. But when the message is in HTML format the BODY TEXT is surrounded by HEADERs text.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you have a properly formatted email, you can use Mail helper methods:

```
mail = Mail.new(email_string)
mail.text_part # finds the first text/plain part
mail.html_part # finds the first text/html part
```

This doesn't always work if you have e.g. single part messages (text only) or receive email from the internet at large since you can't rely on formatting from every client out there. Believe me, I've learned the hard way.

Answer (score 9):

looks like you've got a multipart email, so you can use 
    mail.parts[0].body.decoded
These will probably come in handy too:
    mail.multipart?
    mail.parts.length

The gem documentation at [github](http://github.com/mikel/mail) is pretty decent

Answer (score 2):

With the `mail` gem, you can do:

```
text = mail.multipart? ? mail.text_part.decoded : mail.body.decoded`
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the mail gem and just use email body format with mail.parts[1].body.decoded.