# Ruby Mail gem extract headers and clean up body

Tags: ruby, email, html-email

I'm working with the [Ruby Mail gem](https://github.com/mikel/mail) to try to read and parse out emails. I'm having a similar problem as [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4033376/mail-gem-how-to-clean-up-the-body-string), but the solutions provided only solved half my problems...

There are some email messages that don't respond to `html_part` or `text_part`, yet they are still considered "multipart". That's fine, I'll resort to manually looking at the MIME types. However, there are multipart message that have no parts!

I have a message, that `message.multipart? #=> true`, but `message.parts.length #=> 0`. As such, I can't actually extract a single part :(.

If I look at `message.body` (or `message.body.decoded`), there IS text there, and the type is `text/html`. However, it also has all the header information at the top.

It sounds crazy, but how can I get just the body (or just the headers) of this "multipart" email that has no parts?

#### Edit

Here's one of the messages in question:

```
#<Mail::Message:70280791538440, Multipart: true, Headers: ...>
```

With `message.body`:

```
--XX-2ba4f992ec6d5e224ebeaf78eac50df5\nContent-type: text/html; charset=\"UTF-8\" \nContent-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit \n\nThank you...
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it's because real-world email has all kinds of surprises that don't fit the protocol.

To get the header part and body part:

```
header_part, body_part = message.body.split(/\n\s*\n/m, 2)
```

You may find some useful patterns for your parsing in this file:

```
lib/mail/patterns.rb
```